# deleted a control, did clean, then I can't close visual studio, it says "Could not load file or assembly...'

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I had made a user control which was in the toolbox and i'd dragged onto the form.

I wanted to delete it and draw it back on again(as i'd updated the background image of one of the buttons on it and it hadn't updated yet).

So I deleted that user control.. And for some reason I think at that point I did a clean and rebuild.. perhaps thinking it'd make sure it'd refresh.  But then things went wrong.  It didn't rebuild (understandably).. since there is code that references that user control.  And also, the control isn't showing in the toolbox.  (Normally to get it to show in the toolbox i'd rebuild and worst case i'd restart visual studio).. But visual studio won't close the project..

It gives this error   hpro is the name of my program/project.

I have looked at other questions on SO with that error but they seem to be very specific to a particular dll.. and never to their program itself. Like in their cases it's maybe some third party program where they're missing a dll. But that's not the case with the error in my situation.  As hpro is my project and the current project - the project with the issue.

I don't see why it'd need to load my program as an assembly. It should be building it. Though it can't build it because the user control I need to draw on the form isn't in the toolbox. And I can't get it in the toolbox if I can't rebuild it.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a reference to the dll of your project in your project?

Comment: @RezaAghaei  I seriously doubt it.  If i'd coded such a thing then i'd remember.

Comment: I used git so I did `git stash -u` and checked out to the master, so went back to the last commit, which was fine. Still would be interesting to know how to solve that problem properly though without git.